# Is there a way to pass a "Call-Info" SIP INVITE request header from Twilio?

Tags: twilio, sip, twilio-api

Is there a way to send "Call-Info" header data from Twilio when connecting a SIP call? My Obihai phone uses this header to display additional info on incoming calls.

Twilio documentation says it supports "x-" prefixed custom headers by appending them to the the sip address ([documentation link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip#custom-headers)), however the phone is looking for the "Call-Info" header.

From the ObiHai documentation:

```
If the call comes from a SIP service, the service provider may provide caller-id picture in the INVITE request by
including a Call-Info header with a (http or https) URL to the picture file and the attribute “purpose=icon”. For example:
Call-Info: <{image url here}>;purpose=icon;org="ABC Publishing"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Call-Info header is not used by Twilio nor is there a way to set it.